# Question about Map, String Pointers and Closure

Tags: go

I discovered a bug with my code when I was trying to convert `map[string]string` to `map[string]*string` (conversion is required by the API that I was consuming).

### The Problem

In my first method, I tried to iterate over each entry in the source map, `aMap` and convert the string value of each entry into a string pointer and assign this pointer value to the destination map, `bMap` sharing the same key as `aMap`. I initially expected the dereferenced value held in `bMap` to be the same as `aMap` under the same key. However, it turned out that the deferenced value of `bMap` does not share the same value with `aMap` under the same key.

My questions would be:

1. Why does this problem happen?
2. I was able to resolve the issue using the second method, by first defining a function that receives a string and returns a pointer, that way I was able to correctly return the deferenced value to share the same value as `aMap` under the same key. Why does this method work?
3. Also, just curious, why is `&(*v)` a syntax error in Go? I also tried declaring a dummy variable `val := *v`, and assigning it to `bMap` using `bMap[key] = &val` but to no avail. The error said `invalid indirect of v (type string)`

### Source Code

https://play.golang.org/p/ZG7XS2vJx0y

```golang
func main() {
    aMap := make(map[string]string)
    aMap["foo"] = "bar"
    aMap["bar"] = "baz"
    aMap["baz"] = "foo"

    bMap := make(map[string]*string)
    for k, v := range(aMap){
        bMap[k] = &v
    }

    // first method
    fmt.Println("1st method, map[string]*string, bMap") 
    for k, v := range(bMap){
        fmt.Printf("bMap[%s] = %s / %s, aMap[%s] = %s\n",
        k, *bMap[k], *v, k, aMap[k])
    }

    pString := func(v string) *string{ return &v }
    for k, v := range(aMap){
        bMap[k] = pString(v)
    }

    // second method
    fmt.Println("2nd method, map[string]*string, bMap")
    for k, v := range(bMap){
        fmt.Printf("bMap[%s] = %s / %s, aMap[%s] = %s\n",
        k, *bMap[k], *v, k, aMap[k])
    }

    // expected results
    fmt.Println("Expected result: map[string]string, cMap")
    cMap := make(map[string]string)
    for k, v := range(aMap){
        cMap[k] = v
    }
    for k, v := range(cMap){
        fmt.Printf("cMap[%s] = %s / %s, aMap[%s] = %s\n",
        k, cMap[k], v, k, aMap[k])
    }
}
```

### Output

```
1st method, map[string]*string, bMap
bMap[baz] = foo / foo, aMap[baz] = foo
bMap[foo] = foo / foo, aMap[foo] = bar
bMap[bar] = foo / foo, aMap[bar] = baz
2nd method, map[string]*string, bMap
bMap[baz] = foo / foo, aMap[baz] = foo
bMap[foo] = bar / bar, aMap[foo] = bar
bMap[bar] = baz / baz, aMap[bar] = baz
Expected result: map[string]string, cMap
cMap[baz] = foo / foo, aMap[baz] = foo
cMap[foo] = bar / bar, aMap[foo] = bar
cMap[bar] = baz / baz, aMap[bar] = baz
```

Thank you so much.

Comment: It is covered in the FAQ (which is worth reading): https://golang.org/doc/faq#closures_and_goroutines

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem in method 1 is that you aren't taking the address of the string, you're taking the address of the variable it's in. In Go, `&v` returns the address of variable `v`. When you have a loop like this:

```golang
for k, v := range aMap {
    ...
}
```

The variables `k` and `v` that you declare at the start of the loop are the same variables used throughout the loop. They are just assigned different values on each iteration. Within that loop `&v` always evaluates to the same value: the address of `v`. That's why all of your map entries come out to `"foo"`: `"foo"` is the last value placed in `v`, and it's still there.

You can see this behavior in action by changing the string value. All of the map keys will change:

```
*bMap["foo"] = "quux"
fmt.Println(*bMap["bar"]) // prints "quux"
```

Method 2 works because every call of a function has its own local variables. Go guarantees that if you return the address of a local variable from a function, that variable will be allocated on the heap where it can be used as long as it's needed. So your helper function is telling Go to allocate a new `string` variable, copy the passed-in string to it, then return its address.

Here's another method that will work:

```golang
dMap := make(map[string]*string)
for k, v := range(aMap){
    dMap[k] = new(string)
    *dMap[k] = v
}
```

This allocates a new string variable, saves its address in the map, then copies v into it. If you're going to do this often, the helper function is probably best.

The code you tried like this:

```golang
v := "foo"
val := *v
bMap[key] = &val
```

doesn't work because you're saying, "v is a string; now store the value that string points to in val", but the string isn't a pointer.

Answer (score 2):

The first method in the question uses the address of of the single loop variable `v` for all keys.  The value that you see is the last value set to `v`.

Fix by declaring a new variable for each iteration and taking the address of that variable.

```
bMap := make(map[string]*string)
for k, v := range aMap {
    v := v // declare new variable v initialized with value from outer v
    bMap[k] = &v
}
```

The second method in the question also declares a new variable for each iteration in the loop.  The new variable is the function argument.

This answer shows the idiomatic approach for addressing the issue. See [Go FAQ: What happens with closures running as goroutines?](https://golang.org/doc/faq#closures_and_goroutines) for a discussion of the same issue in the context of closures and goroutines.